# how to taken array values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here i am tried to taken array values but its not working please help me any on if you can.
need to pair each zero th element in single array and respectively all array values dynamically in foreach loop

my array values

```
Array
(
    [basic] => Array
        (
            [0] => 38
            [1] => 33
        )

    [bas_sp] => Array
        (
            [0] => 288
            [1] => 278
        )

    [pass_out_yr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1951
            [1] => 1980
        )

    [grade_ug] => Array
        (
            [0] => 88
            [1] => 83
        )

)
```

i need to pair each element dynamically using foreach loop php

my expected result in array format
        all array elements zero are one array and one as second array please help me any one i tried lot but it never workout.

```
array([0]([0] => 38 ,[1] => 288, [2] => 1951, [3] => 88))
array([0]([0] => 33 ,[1] => 278, [2] => 1980, [3] => 83))
```

Comment: I wonder how would you create an array with same keys. __Incredible!!!__

Comment: me too .. your expected  result is not possible  ..

Comment: please edit your question

Comment: i need zero the elements are in on array and first element in next array

Comment: You need to step back a minute and remember how arrays need unique identifiers to recognize what part of the array you want to access. Think about it... how can you access specific data if there is two exact same keys that are pointing to different memory spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar1=[];
$ar2=[];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($key == 0){
    $ar1[] = $value;
    }

    if($key == 1){
        $ar2[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you only when you know the total sub array values. Loop your main array and add index value to your result array.
like add each 0th value in one array and 1th value in second array as i done below.

```
$array = array(
       'basic' => ['38','33'],
       'bas_sp'=> ['288','278'],
       'pass_out_yr'=>['1951','1980'],
       'grade_ug'=>['88','83']);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $array1[] = $value[0];
        $array2[] = $value[1];
    }
```

Comment: You better explain your explanation than just posting some anonymous code section. You should read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help:

```
$aPluckArr = [];
array_push($aPluckArr,$this->pluck($array,0));
array_push($aPluckArr,$this->pluck($array,1));

function pluck($array,$key)
{
    if(!is_array($array))
        return [];

    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if(!isset($value[$key])) continue;
        array_push($result,$value[$key]);
    }
    return $result;
}
```